# Commerce invoice checkout

Tags: commerce

I have enabled the Pay pal module as a checkout option but I need to add a new option for the customer to request an invoice. I realize I need to modify some rules but it seems that the first item I need is a Payment method which the customer can choose that will fire off the Billy invoice. I have looked everywhere but cannot seem to find a suitable method. Should I use the Exmaple paymnet method and try to modify this?

Cheers
/bo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Commerce Custom Offline Payments](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_cop) to handle this.

Comment: Thank, yes I ended up using this module, and it works fine.